# How do you do Angular Component Testing with an externally hosted Login?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, auth0, e2e-testing

I have no code to show because currently I dont know where to start.

anyone that has done end-to-end testing on an angular app should be familiar with the ng e2e command which spins up a browser and attempts to run tests on the components.

The problem is the app I am testing requires you to login via an Auth0 hosted login screen which then redirects you to the app and a token then gets set in local storage which is checked with each request from then on, if its valid the app's routing takes you to the home page.

My problem is that running ng e2e spins up the app, the standard functionality runs and redirects to the auth0 hosted login screen, protractor then sees that the page its looking at isnt an angular app and the tests / browser close.

Does anyone have any pointers on either setting a fake access token for the purposes of testing or any other way?

Comment: please add code to help you more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no one will see this but if you do look into protractor and how to get an instance of webdriver from it that will allow you to run webdriver (ie selenium) commands on the external site.

Answer (score 1):

I've ended up essentially using the bare webdriver to carry out the log in functions with some strategically placed sleeps. The sleeps are a bit hacky and could be replaced with something like a wait but it did the job for now.

```
it('should log in with test user, expect h1 Welcome on front page', () => {
    return page.clickLogIn()) // my page has a log in button that is in its own page object
        .then(_ => browser.sleep(3000)) // wait for Auth0 page to load
        // from here you use non protractor syntax and follow webdriverjs
        // using "browser.driver"
        .then(_ => browser.driver.findElement(By.name('email')))
        .then(e => e.sendKeys('someone@mail.com'))
        .then(_ => browser.driver.findElement(By.name('password')))
        .then(e => e.sendKeys('23p98pjasrnvaaa'))
        .then(_ => browser.driver.findElement(By.css('button'))) // can't find it by text for some reason
        .then(e => e.click())
        .then(_ => browser.driver.sleep(6000))
        // here we're back to protractor
        .then(_ => element.all(by.cssContainingText('h1', 'Welcome, someone')))
        .then(l => expect(l.length).toBe(1));
});
```

Later on I've abstracted the above into its own function with an if statement conditional on whether the Auth0 page is asking me to log in if I'm the already logged in user for subsequent tests. So in each test the function would either log in or it would click the 'someone@mail.com' button.